# Setting up JNDI with a Tomcat 7 environment using Liferay 6.1

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, liferay, jndi

I'm very confused why this isn't working. The environment is a Liferay 6.1 instance with Tomcat 7 and the database is NOT the default database from Liferay. It's a secondary server that is used for data. So I'm not sure if that matters with Liferay or not.

**web.xml** (located in webapps/conf in Tomcat)

```
<web-app>...
<resource-ref>
    <description>My database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/xxx</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**server.xml** (located in webapps/conf in Tomcat)

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Resource name="jdbc/xxx" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="a" password="y" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx" 
    maxActive="200" maxIdle="25" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

**context.xml** (located in webapps/conf in Tomcat)

```
<context>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/xxx" name="jdbc/xxx" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</context>
```

**Code**:

```
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx");
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

**Error**:

```
2016-12-21 19:13:04 FATAL asdasdsd:128 - Exception thrown in (removed): 
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
```

What am I missing?

**Edit**:

Also confirmed the following:

1. mysql connector is in the path
2. same jar is in the classpath of the portlet

**Second Edit**:

I created a brand new, fresh dynamic web application project with the same configuration and DAO layer and it worked 100%. I have a feeling it's related to Liferay now. Unfortunately..

**Third Edit**:

Tried everything, including this article: http://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

This didn't work either. Same exception. The lack of information about this issue on the Liferay website is amazing to me. Documentation appears to be very much lacking.

Comment: Have you tried without giving java:comp/env/ ?

Comment: @RajkannanIyyappan The `java:comp/env/` is absolutely required.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean tomcat/conf, not webapps/conf.

Comment: @OlafKock - Yeah, sorry about that. According to documentation, I think java:comp/env/ is required.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz when we use ResourceRef, the java:comp/env is not required.  Please look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887967/what-is-resource-ref-in-web-xml-used-for

Comment: @RajkannanIyyappan The `java:comp/env` is absolutely required within Java code. The `resource-ref` configuration does not require it, because the resources are always under that subtree. The configuration and code that is currently showing looks accurate to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone that this helps in the future, because boy was this a pain and not well documented.

I had to add this to the portlet-ext.properties of the Liferay application:

```
portal.security.manager.strategy=none
```

Once I found this link: [Liferay/Tomcat "hot-deploy" closes JNDI connection, how can I keep it open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620798/liferay-tomcat-hot-deploy-closes-jndi-connection-how-can-i-keep-it-open)

It ended up solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution would be (It works for me), Remove the resource-ref from web.xml, remove the Resource from server. xml and remove ResourceLink from context.xml.

Add the resource alone to context.xml,

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/xxx" password="" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx" username=""/>
```

Code (java:comp/env/ is required in this case):

```
 Context ctx = new InitialContext();
 DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/xxx");
 Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Same exception. Thanks for answer though.

Comment: This ended up being a Liferay issue. Thank you for your help!